# Creating a non-symmetric matrix of 1s with non-symmetric diagonal of 0s in R

Tags: r, matrix

EDITED:

I would like to efficiently create a 1452 x 44 matrix, where:

- the first column has 33 zeroes followed by 1419 ones
- the second column has 33 ones, then 33 zeroes, then 1386 ones
  ...
- the thirty third column as 1419 ones followed by 33 zeroes

How can I do this in R? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `1452/44 = 33` What is the rule when you reach the 33rd column ?

Comment: I think your math is off. 1452 / 44 = 33, so following your pattern the 33rd column should have 44 zeroes at the bottom.

Comment: If you want a 33-column matrix as described, set `x1 = 44`, `x2 = 1452`, then `m = matrix(c(rep(rep(0:1, c(x1, x2)), x2 / x1 - 1), rep(0, x1)), ncol = x2 / x1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After edits, moving my comment to an answer:

```
x1 = 44
x2 = 1452
m = matrix(c(rep(rep(0:1, c(x1, x2)), x2 / x1 - 1), rep(0, x1)),
           ncol = x2 / x1)
```

Essentially, you want a pattern of 44 0s then 1452 1s repeated a bunch. We stick on the last set of 44 0s so it ends on 0 and set the dimensions accordingly.